# Connecting 19v 3Ah projector to 4 linked power banks

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm trying to make my projector mobile. As per the title the power adapter gives it 19v 3Ah. Now my idea was to link 4 10Ah power banks and take the 20v down to 19v, giving it about 3 hours of mobile usage.

Questions (need those):
1. Does this work? I've got almost no experience with electronics.
2. How would I go about it?

Any tips?

Comment: You need to figure out the discharge curves of your power banks -- do they maintain 5V each until they're low, or do they gradually decrease voltage as they're used up? (If they gradually decrease, you might end up with <19V very quickly.)

Comment: You can easily step down the 20V to 19V with just a diode.

Comment: "the power adapter gives it 19v 3Ah" Do you mean 19V 3A? There's a big difference between A and Ah. In any case, bridging power banks seems like a bad idea. Try to find a 19V power bank. They do exist.

Comment: Assuming USB power banks and that your 3 Ah is actually 3 A, it's highly unlikley they will supply 3 A.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a normal batteries in series idea.

Connect them in series, like this.

[image]

Check if the power bank can handle a constant discharge of 3A continuously. Most power banks I have encounter can only handle 1-2A output, so this could be a "show stoper".